# jQuery page load

Tags: jquery

I see people using all these different techniques with jQuery. I know the 2nd technique will run on page load. But when will the 1st and the 3rd functions fire? The third technique is used in plugins to avoid conflict right? But that will fire before page load surely? I also added a 4th technique. I would like to know when you should/shouldn't use each technique. And if any of them are bogus let me know!

1st

```
(function($) {

})(jQuery);
```

2nd

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

3rd

```
$(function(){

}());
```

4th

```
jQuery(function($) { 

});
```

5th

```
(function(){

})();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update** He's changed the list of calls in the question, so I'm updating to match.

The first is a hack to avoid conflicts with other libraries which might assign `$`. It is *not* a `ready` handler. The second and third are `ready` event handlers.

From [the jQuery API reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> - $(document).ready(handler)
> - $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
> - $(handler)

So although these three do the same thing, avoid the second.

In jQuery 1.3, `$()` was equal to `$(document)`. [This is no longer true in 1.4](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14).

The fourth looks like a syntax error to me. It essentially assigns a new ready handler, but it passes a function with an argument called `$`. Since this is an event handler, jQuery will pass event info in the first argument. You don't typically want `$` to represent event info.

The fifth defines a new function and then invokes it immediately, passing no arguments. So this:

```
(function(){
    alert("Hi!");
})();
```

Means the same as this:

```
alert("Hi!");
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the 3rd example does not wait until `ready` to execute, no?  It looks like it executes inline and passes the function result to jQuery (essentially doing nothing).

Comment: @Josh I don't think that's right. Aside from the fact that the docs claim they're equivalent, realize that `handler` is a method reference, not a method call. In other words, it's meant to be `$(foo)`, not `$(foo())`.

Answer (score 4):

1st - assigns the $ to jQuery for use only inside the brackets (no conflict version)
2nd is normaln version and 3rd is shorthand :)

more: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Overriding_the_.24-function

**Edit**: Oh yes, the shorthand is:

```
$(function() {
  // your code
});
```

(no parenthesis after function() brackets)

**Edit**: After longer reading my own link, it seems, that the first one *may* only wrap part of code, where `$` symbol is assigned to jQuery, but you still have to use `$(document).ready()`

**Edit**:As for updated list: 5th type: check the other answer, I did not know about that type.

```
jQuery(function($){

});
```

The 4th, however, is used for: 1., attach `$` to jQuery, temporarily overloading (inside brackets) any framework, that has `$` shorthand in use globaly (i.e. prototype) and ALSO is `document.ready` statement.

Comment: You just gave examples for why they're not all the same ;). +1 nonetheless

Comment: The third is not the same as anything.

Comment: I thought the third is a way to create a wrapper around the jQuery object so that it doesn't conflict with other libraries. So surely this has nothing to do with document ready or body load?

Comment: The first one is absolutely not the same as the others, and importantly it's not a "ready" handler.

Comment: @jake - actually, the first one does that. Otherwise, i'm 99% positive all of them start right after dom is loaded.

Comment: So when and why would someone use the 3rd option? Is it used for special cases or just a ready handler?

Comment: as for me (and according to some of us, i'm really confused :]) - I see no reason (as 3rd option with parenthesis is something out of manual - see my respons) to use it. I stick with document.ready, or, If I'll need to use more frameworks - will use other method from jquery.com link i posted (at the end of document)